# AdaCore's GNAT Community Edition on Apple BigSur on Intel Chips

Tags: ada, gnat

Has anyone had success with AdaCore's GNAT Community Edition 2021 on Apple BigSur on Intel Chips?

I am running into problems migrating from my 2012 MacBook Pro Catalina and 2018 Gnat to a 2017 MBP with BigSur, but still on Intel. I get the  newer need for Xcode.

Update: I got everything running on the newer MBP with Bigsur and M1 chipset, but I get an error building the app, after compiling everything using the GPS IDE: missing file `-LSystem`. I don’t find that anywhere so far on the new MacBook with BigSur, but I check on my older MPB where everything works fine.

Comment: It works fine on my 2014 MBP + Big Sur. You should detail your problem(s).

Comment: You may have installed the command line developer tools, which are no longer sufficient; `Xcode.app` is required for recent versions; try `xcode-select -p` to see what's where.

Comment: Thank you flex and trashgod. I will follow your tips.

Comment: AdaCore haven’t released GNAT CE 2021 for macOS. Which release are you actually using? If it’s the release I made [here](https://github.com/simonjwright/distributing-gcc/releases/tag/gnat-ce-2021) or [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuada/files/GNAT_GPL%20Mac%20OS%20X/2021-x86_64-darwin-bin/), you could raise an issue/post a ticket